# ajax-php star rating system (just show the average date from mysql databse)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I need a rating system which shows the average ratings in php. I done the rating process (saving and update process). I need just to show the average rating in php (using php-Ajax rating system).

While I retrive the data from the database I got errors. The code is this:

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if(!$con){
        echo "Connection to the Database Console was Unsuccessful";
    }
    $select = mysql_select_db("oilandgas13",$con);
    if(!$select){
        echo "Connection to the Database was Unsuccessful";
    }

$add_coun= "SELECT sum(rating) sum, count(id) count from comments WHERE item_id = $itemID AND status=1";
        
        $result = mysql_query($add_coun,$con);
        if(!$result)
        {
        echo "query was not successfully";  
        }
        
        $result = mysql_fetch_object($result);
        
        $sum = $result->sum;
        $count = $result->count;
        $rating = $sum / $count;
        
        echo $rating;
?>
```

I got errors like this:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\wamp\www\final work_apr51\final work_apr51\calculation.php on line 19

> Warning: Division by zero in C:\wamp\www\final work_apr51\final work_apr51\calculation.php on line 23

Comment: But what is your question? With what do you have problems? What have you tried that doesn't work?

Comment: You should consider using mysqli or PDO instead of deprecated mysql functions.  You should also add error handling to log the error you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can help you?

```
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","mysqlusername","mysqlpassword","dbname");
    $rating = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
    $q = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM ratings WHERE id='{$rating}'"); //Get our ratings by the page that has rated

    //Die if id dont exist!
    if(mysqli_num_rows($q) == 0) die("Wrong page id!");


    //Select good & bad ratings
    $good = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM ratings WHERE id='{$rating}' AND value ='yes'");
    $bad = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM ratings WHERE id='{$rating}' AND value ='no'");

    //Count good & bad ratings
    $gcnt = mysqli_num_rows($good);
    $bcnt = mysqli_num_rows($bad);

    //Calculate
    $totalVotes = $gcnt + $bcnt;

    if($totalVotes == 0){
      echo $totalVotes." votes";
    }
    if($totalVotes > 0){
      echo "<font color='green'>".$totalVotes." votes</font>";
    }
    if($totalVotes < 0){
      echo "<font color='red'>".$totalVotes." votes</font>";
    }
```

Comment: Thank you doesn't cut it. Upvotes are da real MVP. I'll leave you mine, @OrelBiton